# Downloading Ubuntu 16.04 from bootable USB error

Tags: 16.04, boot, usb

I followed the exact steps of the downloading Ubuntu using bootable USB tutorial but still got nowhere. When I plug in USB into my embedded system, nothing happens. I've tried pressing F12 to get to the boot menu, but no luck. All that's is on the screen is a black screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What embedded system is it? What Ubuntu flle did you download? Did you check it with md5sum (or some other checksum)? Which tool did you use to make a bootable USB drive? Please tell us and help us help you.

Comment: Jetson TK, ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-i386, I did not check it with md5sum, I used Rufus

Comment: I have no experience of Jetson TK (I checked quickly via the internet). Do you know the architecture (for example, can we expect the 32-bit iso files made for intel/amd processors to work with it)?

Comment: 32-bit files should work.

Comment: I suggest that you do some tests to eliminate various causes of the failure to boot the Jetson TK. Can you boot a standard PC from this USB pendrive with Ubuntu? Can you boot the Jetson TK from some other USB pendrive?

Comment: I'll try that now